# How to restore email from a Time Machine backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine, email, restore

Does anyone have experience restoring email from a Time Machine backup? This was easier in earlier versions of MacOS, when Time Machine provided a UI through the Mail program itself. Now it seems to be necessary to go spelunking through the `~/Library/Mail` folder. This *almost* works for me, but I've run into an odd problem.

Here's what I've done (running MacOS 13.1):

1. Go to `~/Library/Mail/V10` in Finder.
2. Enter Time Machine.
3. Go to the last backup that contains deleted messages.
4. Restore the `V10` subdirectory corresponding to the account in question.
5. Exit Time Machine.
6. Open Mail.
7. Select `File/Import`.
8. Select format: `Apple Mail`
9. Select the restored `V10` subdirectory.
10. Select one or more mailboxes from the account to import.

At this point, everything looks good. The selected mailbox(es) are restored to a local folder named `Import`, and when I browse through them, everything seems to be in order.

The problem appears when I try to move selected messages to another mailbox. (I want to do this because the messages are restored to a local mailbox, but originally came from a mailbox on an IMAP server.) After the move, every message that contained attachments appears to have lost all its content. The message body is blank, and even `View ... Raw Source` is blank. `View ... All Headers` shows only `(No Subject)`. Most messages without attachments are unaffected, but a few of these *may* be lost as well. Oddly enough, the same losage occurs when I just rebuild the imported mailbox. It's not clear if this is a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong.

I'm sure I'm not the first person who's wanted to restore email from a backup, but I'm finding very little useful documentation on how to deal with this.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, Apple removed the functionality to browse in Mail some years ago. Send feedback to Apple if you want it restored!

Comment: Yeah, that was another of those "we can't fix it so we'll remove it" decisions. It stopped working properly in Mojave [though it still theoretically should]. It failed entirely when they went to APFS for TM.

Answer (score 3):

I recently did a similar recovery and had the same problem. In a recovered mailbox with about 1500 mails I had some 50 blank messages.
My solution is probably not suitable if hundreds of messages are affected, since it is a one-by-one procedure, but I absolutely needed the content of these 50 messages back:

- Recover the V10 (or a subdirectory) to the desktop via Time Machine.
- In Mail.app, check the date of a blank message.
- In Finder, search inside the V10 for `.emlx` files with the corresponding creation date. In my case, interestingly, all the messages concerned were not `Filename.emlx` but `Filename.partial.emlx`. At this point, QuickLook can be used to prove that the messages in the backup are still intact and only degenerate when they are re-imported into Mail.app via the app's import function. Therefore my unofficial method as follows:
- Edit the filename, delete the `.partial` part.
- Double-click the `Filename.emlx`, it opens in Mail.
- Move it to the desired mailbox via the pull-down in the top right of the message window.
- With some delay, for a mysterious reason a few of the messages were automatically moved again to a newly created Recovered E-Mail mailbox, but when I dragged them back, they stayed where they should.

Later I realized, that the process can be speeded up a bit, if you directly search for `.partial.emlx` in Finder and sort them by creation date. In my case, the number of hits was pretty much the same as the number of blank messages in Mail.app.